# Gazebo world from heightmap in Electric/Fuerte

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte, ros-diamondback, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built some contoured worlds in Gazebo using heightmaps but all on Diamondback.  In order to get some more advanced robot models, I had to upgrade to Electric but now all of my heightmap launch files crash.  I have gone through the tutorials again and still can't get a heightmap to build a world in Gazebo successfully still.  Also tried on a Fuerte build with same error.

Anyone successfully gotten a heightmap world in Electric/Fuerte Gazebo?  If so I would like to see your .world and launch file.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46138/gazebo-world-from-heightmap-in-electric/fuerte/) by [dabigshue](https://answers.ros.org/users/3390/dabigshue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seem to remember that heightmap support was broken in electric but has been re-added in recent gazebo (1.0+) versions. There also is a [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/beginner/heightmap) on using height maps on the new gazebo wiki, so that might be worth a try.

An alternative approach I used in our [hector_gazebo_worlds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo_worlds) package is the use of a COLLADA terrain mesh generated using blender. This works both in electric and fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dabigshue](https://answers.ros.org/users/3390/dabigshue/) on 2012-10-23**:
No luck with the heightmap tutorial.  Was able to use your hector package and the "rolling terrain" world looks great.  I have messed with COLLADA / Blender (creating mesh .dae from heightmap) but was eventually squashed by the learning curve.  Any way to simply sculpt an existing mesh in Blender?